# Is Reference.svcmap compiled in my DLL?

Tags: .net, wcf

I am trying to explain the behavior of a wcf client. 
The client doesn't have any entry in the client.exe.config file, yet it is able to invoke the web service.

So I decompiled the client dll, using dotPeek 1.1, where I make a call to the web service. I am unable to spot any entry that is the end point URL.

I am unable to understand how does the client get an endpoint, when I have removed the binding information from the configuration file.

The client has been written in .NET 4.0 using C#. When I add a service reference, a number of files get generated in the Service Reference folder. Are any of these files then compiled in the binary? **If so, where can I find them?**

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with a "service reference". Please verify that you really don't have the URL values in your config or in your own code, and post additional details, like steps to reproduce.

Comment: Do you use [WCF Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456791(v=vs.110).aspx)? With what code do you invoke the web service call? What do .NET Tracing and/or Fiddler say about the traffic? Does a request end up at your server?

Comment: @JoeEnos I am able to spot the URL entry in a resource file. I was looking a the code in dotPeek. I started to look at the resources next and was able to find an entry there.

Comment: What steps are you taking to do that? And which version of Visual Studio? It would be noteworthy to see why it sometimes puts it in the resources and why sometimes it doesn't. In my scenario, it did not use any resource files.

Answer (score 0):

Only file which is compiled and added to output assembly is Reference.cs/Reference.vb file. All other files are just download and created for conde generation. Reference.svcmap has the xml which contains some of the important switches which decides how proxy code is generated i.e. referenced assemblies, type of serializer to use etc.

HTH,
Amit Bhatia